# How to get konsole work on gns3

Tags: command-line, networking, kde

i am interested in making my devices display in tabs when working on GN3. i made some research and found out that konsole can do that. i installed it. 
i have gone to preferences => edit => set KDE konsole
amazingly when i open the console of a device it 
[image]

i need it to display the router or device i intend working with normally. how do i fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is simple, just to preferences => edit => general, on the tab for console change the command there to

console application commands:
konsole --new-tab -p tabtitle=%d -e telnet %h %p

then {the second console application commands:

Local serial connections (remember to install socat)
konsole --new-tab -p tabtitle=%d -e socat UNIX-CONNECT:"%s" stdio,raw,echo=0

[image]